# zlib build failure on OS X 10.9.2 (Xcode 5.1)

Tags: osx-mavericks, zlib

Upgrading to Xcode 5.1 (and the most recent command line tools) has resulted in my no longer being able to build zlib. I now get the following:

```
gcc -dynamiclib -install_name /Users/fonnescj/Code/lib/libz.1.dylib -compatibility_version 1 -current_version 1.2.5 -arch x86_64 -I/Users/fonnescj/Code/include -I/Users/fonnescj/Code/include/freetype2 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -fPIC -o libz.1.2.5.dylib adler32.lo compress.lo crc32.lo deflate.lo gzclose.lo gzlib.lo gzread.lo gzwrite.lo infback.lo inffast.lo inflate.lo inftrees.lo trees.lo uncompr.lo zutil.lo  -lc -arch x86_64 -L/Users/fonnescj/Code/lib -lbz2 -syslibroot,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -L. libz.a
clang: error: unknown argument: '-syslibroot,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
make[1]: *** [libz.1.2.5.dylib] Error 1
make: *** [zlib] Error 2
```

It was suggested that adding the following flag would fix the issue:

```
export ARCHFLAGS="-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future"
```

but it has not.

Comment: How are you trying to build it?  I just tried zlib 1.2.5 and 1.2.8 on OS X 10.9.2 with XCode 5.1, and had no problem.  I did `./configure` and `make test`.

Comment: My script does the following: ./configure --prefix=${PREFIX} &&\
 ${MAKE} -j3 install

Comment: I have no idea how you're getting that dylib build line.  With `./configure --prefix=foo`, I'm getting `gcc -dynamiclib -install_name foo/lib/libz.1.dylib -compatibility_version 1 -current_version 1.2.5 -O3 -fPIC -o libz.1.2.5.dylib adler32.lo compress.lo crc32.lo deflate.lo gzclose.lo gzlib.lo gzread.lo gzwrite.lo infback.lo inffast.lo inflate.lo inftrees.lo trees.lo uncompr.lo zutil.lo  -lc -L. libz.a`, and it works fine.  Perhaps you have some environment variables set that are confusing the build process.

Comment: It might be. I'm building this inside of a matplotlib (Python) build script, so I will try and check out what they are setting. Thanks.